# "If" with assignment is a good practice?

Tags: php, coding-style

consider this case:

large code:

```
if($site->getUser($id)){
   $user = $site->getUser($id);
   //more code here
}
```

short code:

```
if($user = $site->getUser($id)){
   //already have the user
   //more code here
}
```

in the first case, I do 2 access to bbdd for get the user, but in the second only one...
the second case, is a good practice?

Comment: In the first case you are calling the function ***two*** times (when only once is enough), That gives you your answer :)

Comment: I guess the "correct" short code should be `$user = func(); if ($user) {`

Comment: yes, I'm more comfortable with $user = this_>getUser(); if ($user){....}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer this.

```
$user = $site->getUser($id);
if($user){    
    //more code here
}
```

Generally, assignments in conditions should be avoided. Many programming languages don't even allow it anymore. Too easy to make a mistake.
It's also better in terms of readability.

Comment: And why should they generally be avoided? What's the argument in favor of that statement?

Comment: As I wrote: Mistakes/bugs (confusing = and ==) and readability

Answer (score 0):

Repeatedly calling a function which is potentially expensive and/or has side effects is certainly not a good thing to do in any case, so your first sample should generally be avoided. Exceptions may be if the method is purely a passive getter method which does not execute any logic code; but since this implementation may change, you should still avoid it.

```
if ($foo = bar()) ...
```

Against the above can be argued that typos confusing `=` and `==` are not uncommon, so this may lead to bugs and/or be needlessly confusing to future developers reading the code. The least controversial method should be:

```
$foo = bar();
if ($foo) ...
```

However, some prefer to shorten this to an assignment-in-if; it's a stylistic choice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,in my opinion.
But, i am accustomed to code like this.

```
if($user = ($site->getUser($id) ) ){
   //already have the user
   //more code here
}
```

Warning this

```
if($flag = $usrType == $type) ){
   //already have the user
   //more code here
}
```